# pytest: are pytest_sessionstart() and pytest_sessionfinish() valid hooks?

Tags: pytest

are `pytest_sessionstart(session)` and `pytest_sessionfinish(session)` valid hooks? They are not described in [dev hook docs](http://pytest.org/dev/plugins.html) or [latest hook docs](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html)

What is the difference between them and `pytest_configure(config)`/`pytest_unconfigure(config)`?

In docs it is said:

> `pytest_configure(config)`called after command line options have been parsed. and all plugins
>   and initial conftest files been loaded.

and

> `pytest_unconfigure(config)` called before test process is exited.

Session is the same, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bad news is that the situation with sessionstart/configure is not very well specified. Sessionstart in particular is not much documented because the semantics differ if one is in the xdist/distribution case or not.  One can distinguish these situations but it's all a bit too complicated.

The good news is that pytest-2.3 should make things easier.  If you define a @fixture with scope="session" you can implement a fixture that is called once per process within which test execute.
For distributed testing, this means once per test slave.  For single-process testing, it means once for the whole test run.  In either case, if you do a "--collectonly" run, or "-h" or other options that do not involve the running of tests, then fixture functions will not execute at all.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: How do you ensure (or control) the order that these session-scoped fixtures execute? Will the fixture execute even if there are no tests that depend on it?